# ThreadLocal and generics

Tags: performance, f#

I would like to create some thread local static arrays, using generics. The size of the array depends on the type.  I'm trying to do something like:

```
type LeftoverPool private () =
    static let instance  = new ThreadLocal<'T[]>(fun () -> Array.zeroCreate (Vector<'T>.Count))
    static member Instance = instance.Value
```

But that constrains T to int.
I've tried making the instance method generic, or the type, but can't get this to work.

Comment: You're using statically resolved generic, try the regular kind instead - just replace `^T` with `'T`.

Comment: I've edited the example to use regular generics. The issues remains, however.

Comment: Try specifying where the generic parameter originates. `LeftoverPool< 'T>`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a type perspective, what you're trying to do at the moment really doesn't make sense.

You have a static property `Instance` but its type its completely ambiguous because it's impossible to resolve the meaning of `'T`.  In order to do this you need to propagate the type annotation up to the containing type, e.g.:

```
type LeftoverPool<'T> private () =
    static let instance  = new ThreadLocal<'T[]>(fun () -> Array.zeroCreate<'T> (Vector<'T>.Count))
    static member Instance = instance.Value
```

Comment: Ah, I had tried this but we getting constraint errors, but once I applied them all it looks like this works. Will accept in a bit after some testing.

Comment: @jackmott Yes, if `Vector<'T>` has some constraints on `'T` you would have to apply them to `LeftoverPool<'T>` too.

Comment: Downvoter: perhaps you could explain what you object to about this answer?

Answer (score 2):

Create a generic type, then its static members will be specific for the type. Resharper (for C#) will issue a warning, but here is what you really need.

Also, you need to benchmark `ThreadStatic` vs `ThreadLocal` as well, the later is effectively a pool of objects and it my have some lookup overheads compared to thread-static fields that just reside in a special memory region for each thread.

**Update**

I was going to test it for a while anyway, here is the code and output. ThreadStatic is faster.

```
[TestFixture]
public class BuffersTests {

    public static class LocalBuffers<T> {
        [ThreadStatic]
        private static T[] _threadStatic;
        private static ThreadLocal<T[]> _threadLocal = new ThreadLocal<T[]>(() => new T[10]);
        public static T[] ThreadStatic => _threadStatic ?? (_threadStatic = new T[10]);
        public static T[] ThreadLocal => _threadLocal.Value;
    }

    [Test, Ignore]
    public void ThreadStaticVsThreadLocal() {
        for (int r = 0; r < 10; r++) {

            const int count = 100000000;
            var sw = new Stopwatch();

            sw.Restart();
            var sum = 0L;
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                var buffer = LocalBuffers<int>.ThreadStatic;
                buffer[0] = 123;
                sum += buffer[0] + buffer[1];
            }
            Assert.IsTrue(sum > 0);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"ThreadStatic {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

            sw.Restart();
            sum = 0L;
            for (var i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                var buffer = LocalBuffers<int>.ThreadLocal;
                buffer[0] = 123;
                sum += buffer[0] + buffer[1];
            }
            Assert.IsTrue(sum > 0);
            sw.Stop();
            Console.WriteLine($"ThreadLocal {sw.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

            Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
        }
    }
}


ThreadStatic 1286
ThreadLocal 1860
---------------------
ThreadStatic 1312
ThreadLocal 1849
---------------------
ThreadStatic 1334
ThreadLocal 1933
---------------------
ThreadStatic 1390
ThreadLocal 2076
---------------------
ThreadStatic 1438
ThreadLocal 2088
---------------------
ThreadStatic 1295
ThreadLocal 2216
---------------------
ThreadStatic 1317
ThreadLocal 1972
---------------------
ThreadStatic 1380
ThreadLocal 1943
---------------------
ThreadStatic 1410
ThreadLocal 1970
---------------------
```